# KeyError when training a model with pyspark.ml on AWS EMR with data from s3 bucket

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am training a machine learning model with pyspark.ml on .json data from an s3 bucket on AWS EMR in a JupyterLab notebook. The bucket is not mine, but I think access works fine because data preprocessing, feature engineering etc. works fine. But when I call the `cv.fit(training_data)` function, the training process runs until it almost finishes (indicated by the status bar), but then throws an error:

```
Exception in thread cell_monitor-64:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget-1.0-py3.7.egg/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget/cellmonitor.py", line 178, in cell_monitor
    job_binned_stages[job_id][stage_id] = all_stages[stage_id]
KeyError: 6571
```

I could not find any information on this error yet. What is going on?

This is my pipeline:

```
train, test = clean_df.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2], seed=42)

va1 = VectorAssembler(inputCols="vars", outputCol="vars")

scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="to_scale", outputCol="scaled_features")

va2 = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["more_vars","scaled_features"], outputCol="features")

gbt = GBTClassifier()   

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[va1, scaler,va2,gbt])

paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder()\
    .addGrid(gbt.maxDepth, [2, 5])\
    .addGrid(gbt.maxIter, [10, 100])\
    .build() 

crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                          estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                          evaluator=MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName='f1'),
                          numFolds=3)

cvModel = crossval.fit(train)
```

Second, I have a hunch that I might by resolved in Python 3.8; can I install Python 3.8 on EMR?

Comment: the error states, that the key `6571` is not in your dictionary `job_binned_stages` or `all_stages`

Comment: Can you elaborate what that is supposed to mean? I do not have key 6571 anywhere in the code. I am sorry, but I cannot make any sense out of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem. We are using Hyperopt and we just added try except to avoid this issue. The Error keeps appearing but it keeps running.
It seems that the error affects the bars showing the progress inside the spark jobs on the EMR notebook but it completes the pipeline.

```
# Defining the hyperopt objetive
def objetive(params):
    try:
        # Pipeline here with Vector Assembler and GBT
        return {'loss': -metrics_val.areaUnderPR, 
                "status": STATUS_OK, 
                "output_dict": output_dict}
    except Exception as e:
        print("## Exception", e)
        return {'loss': 0, 
                "status": STATUS_FAIL,
                "except": e,
                "output_dict": {"params": params}}
```

The Exception we got is the following:

```
Exception in thread cell_monitor-18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget-1.0-py3.7.egg/awseditorssparkmonitoringwidget/cellmonitor.py", line 178, in cell_monitor
    job_binned_stages[job_id][stage_id] = all_stages[stage_id]
KeyError: 2395
```

But we got the output from all hyperopt:

```
100%|##########| 5/5 [34:36<00:00, 415.32s/trial, best loss: -0.3907675279893325]
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the code you used for the try/except?

Comment: As we are using hyperopt the try except is on each fit inside the objetive in HyperOpt. We got some exceptions from spark. The same explained above. But it ends up the running, with the model and the scores. I've made an update with the code and the Exception we print. We really don't know why it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error in your code. The key error is referencing the stage number which does not exist. It is some kind of internal Spark monitoring error. I do not However, it does not seem to affect the running of the application.